# Simple cut and paste will not work

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple macro that refuses to work.  It gets to the cut portion and surrounds the information with marching ants; and then...nothing.

What I am trying to accomplish is to find a value (1050) in column D. Whenever I find it, I want to move the entire row of data to the bottom of the sheet.

The worksheet consists of thousands of lines of information and the number of rows changes every month. The columns are constant.

This is what I have:

```
Sub MurrayTest()
    'Dim xRg As Range
    'Dim xTxt As String
    'Dim xCell As Range
    'Dim xEndRow As Long
    'Dim I As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If

    Set xRg = Range("d:d")
    xEndRow = xRg.Rows.Count + xRg.Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For I = xRg.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If xRg.Cells(I) = "1050" Then
           xRg.Cells(I).EntireRow.Cut
           Rows(xEndRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ① Do you get any errors? If so which and where? ② Why did you comment out all your `Dim` it would be a good idea to use them.

Comment: I would put a code break onto the `xRg.Cells(I).EntireRow.Cut` portion to see if you're actually getting to the suspect spot.  Sometimes there are trailing blanks or wotnot.

Comment: Also with xRg you are selecting a column and then later you are using `xRg.Row`.  This is a confusing way to just add 1 since any column.row will always return 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to insert the rows into the last row of the sheet +1.  This is out of bounds.

Instead of this:

```
Set xRg = Range("d:d")
xEndRow = xRg.Rows.Count + xRg.Row
```

Do this:

```
Set xRg = Range("d:d")
xEndRow = Range("d1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
```

This way your just looking at populated cells instead of all possible cells.

**Note**
I prefer using something like `xEndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` because finding the last row from the top can sometimes be incorrect if the dataset isn't complete.  You may need to play with different approaches to determine what's best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If i read this correctly, you want to find the value 1050 on Column D, if it is found you want this row Cut and Inserted at the end of the list.

```
Sub MurrayTest()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xEndRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set xRg = Range("D:D")
    xEndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(Excel.xlUp).Row + xRg.Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = xEndRow To 1 Step -1
        If xRg.Cells(i) = "1050" Then
           xRg.Cells(i).EntireRow.Cut
           Rows(xEndRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey great answer that is exactly the same as mine **thumbs up bro**

Comment: No problem. He is still using the last row of the sheet in the for loop by just applying your fix.